# Shopware: Remove Add To Cart for Some products

Tags: shopware

Within Shopware 6, has anyone figured out how to remove the “add to cart” button for some products? My goal is to allow the add to cart on most items, but I’d like the option/ability to remove it for select products.

Thanks in advance!

Scott

Answer (score 4):

You can use a custom field for this.

In admin go to Settings / Custom fields and add a new custom field set. Name it for example `custom_product` and assign `Products`, save. Then add a new custom field. Name it for example `custom_product_remove_buy_button` and choose `Active switch` as type.

Alternatively, you can create the custom field programmatically as described in the [documentation](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/custom-field/add-custom-field#adding-an-actual-custom-field).

You will see the new custom field in admin in product detail under Specifications / Custom fields.

Then you can use the custom field in a template to disable the "add to cart" button in the storefront. In order to remove the button on the product detail page, create a new file `src/Resources/views/storefront/page/product-detail/buy-widget.html.twig` in your theme or plugin and paste the following code:

```
{% sw_extends '@Storefront/storefront/page/product-detail/buy-widget.html.twig' %}

{% block page_product_detail_buy_form %}
    {% if page.product.active and page.product.customFields.custom_product_remove_buy_button != true %}
        <div class="product-detail-form-container">
            {% sw_include '@Storefront/storefront/page/product-detail/buy-widget-form.html.twig' %}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

To remove the button in the product listing, create a file `src/Resources/views/storefront/component/product/card/action.html.twig`:

```
{% sw_extends '@Storefront/storefront/component/product/card/action.html.twig' %}

{% block component_product_box_action_buy %}
    {% if product.customFields.custom_product_remove_buy_button != true %}
        {{ parent() }}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Additionally I would also overload the CartProcessor and remove all line items associated with these products.

Comment: Long overdue, but I would like to say thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Setting the *Max. order quantity* to 0 will result in not showing a buy button on the product detail page. However it is still possible to add the product via the listing. To fix this you can extend this file as mentioned before:

> src/Resources/views/storefront/component/product/card/action.html.twig

```
{% block component_product_box_action_buy %}
    {% if product.calculatedMaxPurchase > 0 %}
        {{ parent() }}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

If the user somehow manages to add the product in the cart Shopware will throw a default error message:

> The product "Test" is not available any more

Comment: Long overdue, but I wanted to say thank you for helping with the answer here!